# Find every transformation of a variable in a formula or a regression table

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to find every transformation of a variable in a formula (in a time series problem) or alternatively, find the position of every transformation of a variable in the vector of coefficients in the regression analysis associated to this formula.

Let's assume the following example:

```
library(xts)
library(dyn)

n <- 100
dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("01-01-01"), length.out = n, by = "months")
X1 <- xts(rnorm(n, 0, 2), dates)
X2 <- xts(rnorm(n, 0, 2), dates)
X3 <- xts(rnorm(n, 0, 2), dates)
Y <- xts(rnorm(n, 0, 2), dates)
data <- merge.xts(Y, X1, X2, X3)

fla <- Y ~ lag.xts(Y,1) + X1 + X2 + diff.xts(log(X1), 1) + exp(X1) + lag.xts(X2 + X3, 1)
model <- dyn$lm(fla, data = data)

summary(model)
```

And the output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dyn(fla), data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6017 -0.7453  0.1471  0.9604  2.4439 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          -0.21310    0.99148  -0.215    0.832
lag.xts(Y, 1)        -0.06777    0.16848  -0.402    0.691
X1                    0.08185    0.73443   0.111    0.912
X2                   -0.11891    0.15018  -0.792    0.436
diff.xts(log(X1), 1) -0.01050    0.38079  -0.028    0.978
exp(X1)               0.01028    0.04157   0.247    0.807
lag.xts(X2 + X3, 1)  -0.09484    0.08746  -1.084    0.288

Residual standard error: 1.712 on 26 degrees of freedom
  (67 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1129,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.09183 
F-statistic: 0.5514 on 6 and 26 DF,  p-value: 0.7644
```

There are 4 variables in the regression (`Y`, `X1`, `X2` and `X3`). My goal is to find the correspondance:

```
Y -> c(2)
X1 -> c(3, 5, 6)
X2 -> c(4, 7)
X3 -> c(7)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for text processing. R offers extensive facilities to deal with model terms.

```
foo <- \(model) {
  vars <- attr(terms(model), "variables")
  
  sel <- lapply(vars, all.vars)[-1]
  
  res <- lapply(all.vars(terms(model)), \(x) which(sapply(sel, \(y) x %in% y)))
  setNames(res, all.vars(terms(model)))
}

foo(model)
#$Y
#[1] 1 2
#
#$X1
#[1] 3 5 6
#
#$X2
#[1] 4 7
#
#$X3
#[1] 7
```

Obviously, the indices start with the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grepl` for each variable name with `sapply`:

```
sapply(names(data), function(y) which(grepl( y, names(model$coefficients), fixed = TRUE)))
$Y
[1] 2

$X1
[1] 3 5 6

$X2
[1] 4 7

$X3
[1] 7
```

Comment: This can be shortened by directly using `grep` instead of `grepl` with `which` as follows: `sapply(names(data), function(name) grep(pattern = name, names(model$coefficients), fixed = TRUE))`. However, our approaches suffer from returning false positives, e.g. consider variables named `X` and `X2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution doesn't work if some variable names are part of some others? Let's assume we add another variable ```X21 <- xts(rnorm(n, 0, 2), dates)```, then if we change ```data```to be ```data <- merge.xts(Y, X1, X2, X3, X21)``` and finally the formula as, for instance, ```Y ~ lag.xts(Y,1) + X21 + X2 + diff.xts(log(X1), 1) + exp(X1) + lag.xts(X2 + X3, 1)```, the output of this solution for ```X2``` and ```X21``` are:
```$X2
[1] 3 4 7

$X21
[1] 3
```
where ```3```should not be included for ```X2```.

Answer (score 0):

We can exploit the set of characters that constitute valid R identifiers (i.e. valid symbol names; see [Identifiers](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Identifiers) for more details) in conjunction with regular expressions to extract the indices you want from `names(model$coefficients)`.

```r
sapply(names(data), 
       function(name) {
  grep(pattern = paste0("^", name, "$|[^:alnum:_.]", name, "[^:alnum:_.]"), 
       names(model$coefficients))
  }
)
```

Output:

```r
$Y
[1] 2
$X1
[1] 3 5 6
$X2
[1] 4 7
$X3
[1] 7
```

##### Explanation

- R only permits alphanumeric characters, underscores or the dot as valid symbol names so we use a group negation `[^:alnum:_.]` to exclude this set to the left or right of the symbols
- We also allow for the case of a standalone symbol with the beginning of string and end of string special characters `^` and `$` respectively
- Since the use of a function to transform a variable necessarily places an excluded character on *both* sides of the symbol (using operands like `+`, `-` or `/` lead to invalid model formulae), we need not handle the one-sided edge case.